# How to make design main and subreport report

Tags: jasper-reports

I made main and subreport design,it's mismatch main report's column and subreport report's column.i want proper design,but don't know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen u post a lots of basic question about jasper report, plus u dont show your code here that make people hard to help u. i recommend u to find a good resources either in stackoverflow or jaspersoft community forum or other sources before start asking.

Here you can start with:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/subreports-jaspersoft-studio

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_create_subreports.htm

http://www.ongraph.com/blog/working-with-subreports-element-in-jasper-studio

https://www.richardnichols.net/2010/02/simple-guide-to-sub-reports-in-jasperreports-ireport/

http://dynamicreports.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=22

Comment: Actually i can't upload design of image